# C# Привязать свой scrollbar к TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

Как привязать свой VScrollBar к TableLayout панели?

Comment: Не знаю но это на Grid похоже из wpf и как ты зачем там прокрутка

Comment: Ее по идеи не буде там